# tibco static bridge queue vs static durable

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems

I am new at working on TIBCO's JMS queue and would like to know the following.

Consider a company with multiple departments

- department A
- department B
- department C

A message recieved from an external source needs to used by different departments. Should each department's client have a **tibco static bridge queue** or a **static durable** on topic?

What are the advantages / disadvantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you already know the difference between JMS Queue and JMS Topic, (jms queue != FIFO) else please see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service][1] Then there is the whole question of Security that is not address here.

So lets assume that security is taking care off, the main question is, if the client will have a process that will sit there and pull messages from the queue, then the queue is fine, but if they will create a process that subscribes to an specific channel then you want a queue.

I seen cases where all departments drop messages into the same queue, then their client take the messages marked only for them from the queue, this could be done with jms property set and selectors.

This solution is more an implementation type of solution that will change how the client read messages from the "place holder" queue/topic, as performance goes, both perform really well on TIBCO EMS. I have seen well over 1 million messages/sec of throughput. The speed in which the messages move is also dictated on what the "service does/how long it takes" and the client reading them.

If performance on both the client-and-service level was taking under consideration the EMS system will perform well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to compare:

Option 1 - An "Input" Topic bridged (as in EMS destination bridges) to many department queues

vs

Option 2 - Static Durable subscription from all departments to the same Input Topic

Here are the differences I see up front:
Queues and static Durable subscribers have to be configured in different config files, and there is a lot more flexibility with queue setup : You can choose the store (fs location), persistence options, expiration options, etc.
Queues can be routed on multiple instances (one-hop limit), topics can be routed too, but static durable subscriptions will have to be set up locally on the destination server.

In short, they are almost the same, but queues offer more configuration options over static durable subscriptions.

possible experiment note : Would a static durable subscription "borrow" some properties from the target queues ? Ex : use the same store as the topic ?

last note : non-static durable subscriptions (durable trigger by client, without config) might be a more noteworthy feature IMHO... but not what you are looking for. Static durable are so similar to queues that they might not be worth your time.